# grep invading my ps

Tags: grep, process, osx, process-management

When I'm checking for some process, I usually write

```
ps aux | grep myprocess
```

And *sometimes* I get the output of

```
eimantas 11998  0.0  0.0   8816   740 pts/0    S+   07:45   0:00 grep myprocess
```

if the process is not running.

Now I really wonder why grep is in the list of processes if it filters out the output of the `ps` command *after* `ps` has run?

Answer (score 13, accepted):

This behavior is totally normal, it's due to how bash manages pipe usage.

pipe is implemented by bash using the [`pipe`](http://linux.die.net/man/2/pipe) syscall. After that call, bash forks and replaces the standard input ([file descriptor 0](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/File_descriptor)) with the input from the right process (`grep`). The main bash process creates another fork and passes the output descriptor of the fifo in place of the standard input ([file description 1](http://linux.die.net/man/2/dup)) and launches the left command.

The `ps` utility is launched after the `grep` command, so you can see it on the output.

If you are not convinced by it, you can use `set -x` to enable command tracing. For instance:

```
+ ps aux
+ grep --color=auto grep
+ grep --color=auto systemd
alexises  1094  0.0  0.8   6212  2196 pts/0    S+   09:30   0:00 grep --color=auto systemd
```

For more explanation you can check this part of basic c shell: http://www.cs.loyola.edu/~jglenn/702/S2005/Examples/dup2.html

Comment: Yes, you're true, I made a misstake,

Answer (score 8):

When I'm only interested in presence of a process, I use `pgrep` which doesn't show this behaviour, e.g.:

```
$ pgrep myprocess
1900
```

In other cases (when I'm interested in more info), I usually add a `| grep -v grep` to discard grep lines, e.g.:

```
$ ps -ef | grep myprocess| grep -v grep
```

Comment: If you want to maintain color highlighting of the matched string use `ps | grep --color=always myprocess | grep -v grep`

Comment: @RyanLoremIpsum Or just reorder the two grep commands like `ps -ef | grep -v grep | grep myprocess`

Comment: So inconsistent. Why does it work that way and not the other? v_v

Comment: Because the colors are being stripped in the pipeline

Comment: A time-honored trick to help this is `ps -ef|grep [m]yprocess`

Answer (score 7):

The `pipe` does not behave like `;`. It starts both the processes together. Which is why the `grep` command showed up too. So when you gave `ps aux | grep myprocess` , the `ps aux` included the `grep myprocess`, so the grep included that in its output.

To check this, I gave two `dd` commands on my test server like this:

```
[sreeraj@server ~]$ dd if=/dev/urandom of=/home/sreeraj/myfile1 bs=1M count=1024 | dd  if=/dev/urandom of=/home/sreeraj/myfile2 bs=1M count=1024
```

And when I checked for the `dd` process, it shows that it both has started at the same time(look at the coloumn that says 2:55 minutes has elapsed) :

```
[sreeraj@server ~]$ ps aux | grep 'dd if'
sreeraj  14891  100  0.2   5376  1416 pts/0    R+   11:56   2:55 dd if=/dev/urandom of=/home/sreeraj/myfile1 bs=1M count=1024
sreeraj  14892  100  0.2   5376  1412 pts/0    R+   11:56   2:55 dd if=/dev/urandom of=/home/sreeraj/myfile2 bs=1M count=1024
sreeraj  14936  0.0  0.1   9032   672 pts/1    S+   11:59   0:00 grep --color=auto dd if
[sreeraj@server ~]$
```

Now, if you want to exclude the grep from getting outputted, use regex. It will exclude the `grep` from the result:

```
ps aux | grep "[m]yprocess"
```

For example, if you are looking for httpd process, use:

```
ps aux | grep "[h]ttpd"
```

But I suggest you use `pgrep -a`, which will be more reliable.

```
[sreeraj@server ~]$ pgrep -a httpd
8507 /usr/sbin/httpd -DFOREGROUND
8509 /usr/sbin/httpd -DFOREGROUND
8510 /usr/sbin/httpd -DFOREGROUND
8511 /usr/sbin/httpd -DFOREGROUND
8513 /usr/sbin/httpd -DFOREGROUND
8529 /usr/sbin/httpd -DFOREGROUND
[sreeraj@server ~]$
```

Comment: `[my]process.` would match `mprocessX` and `yprocessY` (since `[my]` is a character class which matches on of the letters `m` or `y`, and `.` matches anything).

Comment: `pgrep -a` does not seem to be available to me in `pgrep -V` `pgrep from procps-ng 3.3.3`.

Comment: @RyanLoremIpsum - Did you check the `man` page.

Answer (score 3):

You're correct, that's not how it works.  The shell doesn't wait for the first process in a pipeline to exit before starting the next.  It starts them all.  As such, the `ps` may see the `grep` already running.

Comment: Do you mean "You're incorrect"?  The rest continues as if that's what you mean.

Answer (score 2):

Consider this thought experiment: if `ps` ran to completion before invoking `grep` as you think it should, that would mean that the shell would need to:

1. Invoke `ps`.
2. Buffer all of its output (because it has nowhere else to go yet).
3. Invoke `grep`.
4. Feed the saved output to `grep`'s `stdin`.

This is wasteful; it's a more efficient use of memory to invoke `grep` first, let it wait for input, then feed `ps`'s `stdout` directly to `grep`'s `stdin`.

Or, taken to the extreme, consider the case of piping the output of a program that generates an infinite amount of output, e.g.:

```
$ yes | less
```

If the shell ran `yes` before `less`, you would be left waiting forever (or until you completely exhaust your computer's memory).

Answer (score 1):

Just confirming as BowlOfRed and alexises stated. Here is a visual representation piping `ps` and `grep` back to `ps` again to show how the piped processes run. Note that the final `ps x --forest` is ignoring the input, but it keeps the previously piped processes alive so they will be displayed.

`ps -ef | grep myprocess | ps x --forest`

Excerpt of output:

```
25056 pts/3    Ss     0:05  \_ bash
12243 pts/3    R+     0:00  |   \_ ps -ef
12244 pts/3    S+     0:00  |   \_ grep --color=auto myprocess
12245 pts/3    R+     0:00  |   \_ ps x --forest
```

Notice bash is in the interruptible sleep state `S` (waiting for an event to complete). The `s` indicates it is the session leader, as you will see below.

With the `-ef` option you can also see that the child processes are running under the same parent ID which is the process ID of `bash`, `25056`.

`ps x | grep myprocess | ps -ef --forest`

Excerpt of output:

```
UID         PID   PPID   C STIME TTY          TIME  CMD
iamuser     25056 16737  0 Dec23 pts/3    00:00:05  \_ bash
iamuser     12161 25056  0 05:02 pts/3    00:00:00  |   \_ ps x
iamuser     12162 25056  0 05:02 pts/3    00:00:00  |   \_ grep myprocess
iamuser     12163 25056  0 05:02 pts/3    00:00:00  |   \_ ps -ef --forest
```