# ps ax showing process or not

Tags: process, background-process

When I execute `ps ax` command with `grep`, it' showing a single entry of `test.py`

`test.py` was just single print statement submitted like this:

```
nohup python test.py &
```

So I'm assuming it didn't take long to run. Should that entry still be there?

```
$ ps ax | grep test.py
18225 pts/0    S+     0:00 grep test.py
```

Comment: Your `ps` is showing the `grep` process that's filtering the `ps` output for `test.py`, not a `python` process running the thing...

Comment: How can I tell the difference between a running process that was found with grep versus the filtering?

Comment: _How can I tell the difference..._ One will say `grep`, the other will say `python`.  See the above suggested link re `grep -v grep`

Comment: Actually, it is a direct duplicate of https://unix.stackexchange.com/q/176749/5132 .